# SQL max group between times with SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have this structure of data:

```
Date             |Data1 |Data2|Data3
04/01/2016 01:00 |5     |4    |3     
04/01/2016 03:00 |1     |12   |31      
04/01/2016 05:00 |7     |6    |2  
04/01/2016 19:00 |4     |32   |23  
04/01/2016 21:00 |11    |24   |33  
04/01/2016 23:00 |8     |52   |7 
04/02/2016 02:00 |18    |62   |2
04/02/2016 04:00 |4     |5    |75
```

I'm using SSRS to show the maximum of each Data between 7:00am - 7:00pm and 7:00pm to 7:00am the next day.  I started off my creating 2 stored procedures, one to handle the AM data and one to handle the PM data.  This is great, except I need to pass a range of dates and group the AM and PM on those dates.  I did some digging, my only solutions are re-wrting my AM/PM queries so they are in 1 query or somehow join my 2 stored procedures within SSRS.  Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Is there any difference between normal SQL and SSRS? because that look very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this in one query and output it to your report? Adjust the `CASE` statement as required for your AM/PM groupings.

```
WITH AmPmData AS
(
    SELECT
        Date
    ,   CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Date) < 7
                THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(Date AS DATE))
            ELSE CAST(Date AS DATE)
        END AS ReportingDate
    ,   CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Date) < 7
                THEN 'PM'
            WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Date) >= 19
                THEN 'PM'
            ELSE 'AM'
        END AS AmPm
    ,   Data1
    ,   Data2
    ,   Data3

    FROM
        SomeTable

    WHERE
        Date >= @StartDate
        AND Date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
)

SELECT
    ReportingDate
,   AmPm
,   MAX(Data1) AS MaxData1
,   MAX(Data2) AS MaxData2
,   MAX(Data3) AS MaxData3

FROM
    AmPmData

GROUP BY
    ReportingDate
,   AmPm
```

Comment: I think you may need a fix... because your `group by` generate separated the `7pm-7am` range in `DAY pm` and `DAY+1 pm`

Comment: True, I've updated the answer. I've not tested it but the idea is there.

Comment: That works!  But how do you suggest getting SSRS to know which data to reference?  In my textboxes I have to declare which field I want to show, so if I choose MaxData1 SSRS doesn't know to pick the MaxData1 AM or MaxData1 PM.  Does that make sense?

Comment: So each max column represents a measure and you only want to display one? You could use column visibility in your report which is driven by a parameter or unpivot the data in the query and filter the results there.

Comment: What about taking the PM data and making those 2 new columns.  So I'd have twice the amount of columns but 1 would be MaxData1_AM and the other would be MaxData1_PM.  Is that possible?

Comment: You could, it's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve without seeing the desired output. There are many solutions but generally think rows instead of columns and do presentational stuff in your report.

Comment: I don't know how to show a report on here or I would.  My report is simple, a bunch of textboxes that show the max for each data.  The tricky part is I have AM data and PM data.  With your solution (which works great) if I reference the field MaxData1 SSRS will select the first MaxData1, regardless of the AMPM column.  I'm not sure if there's more I can do to that Textbox to filter out the AMPM...

Comment: If you only want to display one of AM or PM and not both then just filter the dataset by the AmPm column. Why bring in the other data if you aren't going to use it? I suggest starting a new question and provide a screenshot of your report.

Comment: No dice.  I got an answer that you can't filter in textboxes.